# Postgres json type inner Query

Tags: json, postgresql

While using Json type in postgresql

data

---

> {{"name":"Roy","Country":"USA","Hobby":"Swim"},{name:"Roy",Country:"USA","Hobby":"Crcket"},{"name":"Anam","country":"Greece","Hobby":"Polo"}}

how can i get all matching values with `data->>name="Roy"`?

O/P should be : `{{"name":"Roy","Country":"USA","Hobby":"Swim"},{name:"Roy",Country:"USA","Hobby":"Crcket"}}`

How can i query for such condition?

Comment: Cross post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/87493/1822

Comment: We do not appreciate crossposts, especially without telling so. Even less questions that are missing most of the essential context: Postgres version, table definition, what you tried. For starters, your JSON value is ***invalid***, quotes are missing. You probably meant a JSON array with square brackets: `'[{"name":"Roy","Country":"USA","Hobby":"Swim"},{"name":"Roy","Country":"USA","Hobby":"Cricket"},{"name":"Anam","Country":"Greece","Hobby":"Polo"}]'::json`